# Kendo UI Dropdownlist checked

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui function dropdownlist, and it will call at Grid column editor. My question, by default how to display "**Yes**" when **Add New Record** in edit function. Currently it display null when Add New Record.

[Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iqowufal)

Here I provide a working demo. *Thank You*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you only have to add a default value to the Price in the Model?

```
"Price": {type: "string", defaultValue: "y" },
```

I include the whole function, just in case:

```
$(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: [
       { Name: "Young John", Price: "y" },
       { Name: "John Doe", Price: "n" },
       { Name: "Old John", Price: "y" }
      ],
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "id",
          fields: {
            "id": { type: "number" }, 
            "Price": {type: "string", defaultValue: "y" }, 
          }
        }
      }
    },
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [{ field: "Name"}, 
              { field: "Price",
                        template: "#=(data.Price == 'y' ? 'Yes' : 'No')#",
                editor: radioPrice
              } ],
    edit: function(e) {     
       if (e.model.isNew()) {       
                        e.model.Price = 'y';
       }
    }
  });
});
```